# Call Plugin within jquery-ui slider function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autosize

I am using a range-slider from jquery ui and want to call another plugin ([autosize](https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input)) from its `slide` function. But in this way it does not work:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 100000,
  max: 5000000,
  step: 100000,
  animate: true,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#range_max" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ])).autosizeInput();
  },
});
```

How to call the `autosizeInput()` on the `#range_max` `input` field?

Comment: You could try binding an event listener to the slide event. - $( ".selector" ).on( "slide", function( event, ui ) {} );

Comment: Do you know you have currently one unnecessary `)` on `ui.values[ 1 ])` ?

Comment: @mark_c this is same problem and does not work. seems that the plugins function cannot be called within a function.

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt Just a transcription mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a work-around where I bind a function to the `input` event of the text box and trigger it when the slider is moved.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 100000,
  max: 5000000,
  step: 100000,
  animate: true,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#range_max" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]).trigger('input');
  }
});

$("#range_max").on("input", function() {
  $(this).autosizeInput();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/rq5q10ok/6/)**

Comment: Sorry. Should have given my resource for autosizeInput (https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input). It is ment for inputs. It also has an update event mentiont in the issues but not in the docs and its not clear how to call it. When I call the autosizeInput() from outside the slider event it does resize the input.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a work-around and example fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, Yass. Thats it. Btw, the fiddle code is different and does not work as good as the one here.